Find Excel interpolated plot x value
How to find the x value to a function value (y) of Excel's default (interpolated) line plot (e.g. at the intersection of the horizontal line)?
Is there a built-in function to do so?
The error that a linear interpolation causes is obvious, so I've tried fitting the data with a polynomial - without success. If Excel's interpolation method is known and could be used for a fit, that might be a good solution, too.


In Excel, Bezier curves are used to interpolate in charts. This is described in detail in this article
https://blog.splitwise.com/2012/01/31/mystery-solved-the-secret-of-excel-curved-line-interpolation/ http://www.xlrotor.com/smooth_curve_bezier_example_file.zip? There is a sample file attached there. However, the code is quite complicated and I think that in this case less advanced interpolation methods should suffice.

Thanks, the blog post is still there, but it looks like the file is blocked by my IT. Other code on the MS forums: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-does-excel-plot-smooth-curves/c751e8ff-9f99-4ac7-a74a-fba41ac80300

It's an old file. Use http protocol instead of https. http://www.xlrotor.com/smooth_curve_bezier_example_file.zip

Not sure this is what you want. There is a graph option you can select that shows the interpolated equation. I would either flipped the plots of x and y or use the MINVERSE formula on the equation shown.

If there's no builtin function, then the only way I can see is to reimplement Excel's interpolation function and determine the value either with it's inverse or by doing a search/approximation.
